# Pylint not running as expected in VScode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, lint

When I am running via shell a `pylint`:

```
$ pylint decorator.py 
No config file found, using default configuration
************* Module decorator
C:  7, 0: Unnecessary parens after 'print' keyword (superfluous-parens)
C: 15, 0: Unnecessary parens after 'print' keyword (superfluous-parens)
C:  1, 0: Missing module docstring (missing-docstring)
C:  4, 0: Missing function docstring (missing-docstring)
C:  6, 4: Missing function docstring (missing-docstring)
C: 14, 0: Missing function docstring (missing-docstring)
```

However, as it can be seen below, these warning do not come up in VSCode

[image]

... despite the fact that some basic  checking is indeed performed as it shown in the next picture where I have removed a blank line:

[image]

Comment: Based on "Unnecessary parens after 'print' keyword", your shell `pylint` is probably running in Python 2 – `print` is not a keyword in Python 3.

Comment: But I installed `pylint` via `pip3` : `sudo -HE pip3 install pylint`

Comment: @pkaramol Installing `pylint` via `python3 -m pip install pylint` (probably `sudo` needed) ensures that it will be installed in the correct environment (usually Python 3.x).

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Assuming you have configured Python's Extension correctly and you have Pylint installed,

VSCode's Python Extension will do [minimal checking by default](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/linting#_default-pylint-rules) if you do not provide a Pylint configuration option.

Simply enter `"python.linting.pylintUseMinimalCheckers": false,` into your `.vscode/settings.json` to force this off.

This is how mine looks:

```
{
    "autoDocstring.docstringFormat": "numpy",
    "editor.minimap.enabled": false,
    "editor.selectionClipboard": false,
    "python.pythonPath": "/home/jim/anaconda3/envs/dipoleDisplay",
    "window.zoomLevel": 0,
    "terminal.integrated.rendererType": "dom",
    "python.linting.pylintUseMinimalCheckers": false,
}
```

> [image: after setting]

Comment: This `python.linting.pylintUseMinimalCheckers` doesn't appear to exist anymore as of Feb. 2022 – it shows up as “Unknown Configuration Setting” in the json editor.

Answer (score 12):

I had a similar problem where flake8 worked in VSCode but pylint didn't.  Here are all the steps I had to check for pylint to start working:

1. Your **.vscode\settings.json** file enables linting by pylint
   (this can be hand edited or by running these command palette commands: **Python: Enable Linting** and **Python: Select Linter**)

   "python.linting.enabled": true

   "python.linting.pylintEnabled": true
2. from the command line (while in virtual environment) confirming that pylint and pylint-django are installed.

   pip show pylint

   pip show pylint-django
3. Add a **.pylintrc** file to your root directory that includes these lines.

   [MASTER]

   load-plugins=pylint_django

(NOTE: you can replace this pylintrc file with the following line in settings.json.)

```
"python.linting.pylintArgs": ["--load-plugins", "pylint_django"]
```

For more info about using pylint in VSCode, see https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/linting#_pylint

For more info about the pylintrc file, see https://docs.pylint.org/en/1.6.0/run.html#command-line-options

Comment: This solution (install pylint and pylint_django) worked for me. My final settings.json ended up being a mix of the accepted and this answer.

Comment: Could you clarify why you use pylint_django, as opposed to say, just pylint?

Comment: NOTE: there is a step missing if you use the python extension. Verify that the selected environment (lower left) is the one that you want, and that has `pylint` installed.

Answer (score 1):

I'm add json to my vscode project folder settings:

```
{
  ...
  "pylint.path": [
    "/home/username/.local/bin/pylint"
  ],
  "pylint.args": [
    "--rcfile=api/.pylintrc"
  ],
  ...
}
```

It working for me. My python files and .pylintrc file placed in `./api/` folder, which is subfolder of my project's root.